# PowerShell - Writing a new GUID for a board with curly braces

Tags: powershell

I start with powershell, and I wrote a small and simple code that writes a new GUID to the board.

I used this line:

```
Set-Clipboard (New-Guid).Guid
```

It works, but I could not find how to write the GUID with curly brackets.

Surely there are already answers on the subject, but I had a hard time finding.

Maybe give someone an idea?

Thank you!

Comment: you just want the guid but wrapped in curly braces? `{guidHere}` like that?

Comment: exactly! This is what I'm looking for!

Comment: `Set-Clipboard "{$((New-Guid).Guid)}"` should be like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Subexpression operator `$( )`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#subexpression-operator--) allows to resolve the expression embedded in the *string*.

Note that calling the `.Guid` property of the object is not needed in this case since the *string* representation of it resolves to the *32 digits separated by hyphens*, same as `.ToString()` or `.ToString('D')`.

```
Set-Clipboard "{$(New-Guid)}"
# `$(New-Guid)` is evaluated first then the result of the expression
# is embedded in the string.
```

[zett42's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7571258/zett42) helpful comment provides a much better alternative to the one above simply by using [Guid `.ToString(String)` Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.tostring?view=net-6.0#system-guid-tostring(system-string)) with the **`"B"` format parameter**:

```
Set-Clipboard (New-Guid).ToString('B')
```

Comment: This is indeed more useful for me, if I include PowerShell commands within a CMD batch script.

Answer (score -2):

**Code**

```
$guid = [System.Guid]::NewGuid().ToString("B")
Write-Host $guid
Set-Clipboard $guid
```

```
$guid = "{$([System.Guid]::NewGuid())}"
Write-Host $guid
Set-Clipboard $guid
```

```
$guid = "{$((New-Guid).Guid)}"
Write-Host $guid
Set-Clipboard $guid
```

```
$guid = (New-Guid).Guid
Write-Host "{$guid}"
Set-Clipboard "{$guid}"
```

**Output**
[image: guid]

---

**Alternative implementation / Cryptographic Guid**

```
function New-CryptoGuid {
        $bytes = [System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator]::GetBytes(16)
        return [System.Guid]::new($bytes).ToString("B")
}

$guid = New-CryptoGuid
Write-Host $guid
Set-Clipboard $guid
```

**Output**
[image: crypto guid]

---

**References**

[System.Guid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid?view=net-6.0)
[Guid.NewGuid Method - Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.newguid?view=net-6.0#remarks)
[System.Guid - Constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.-ctor?view=net-6.0#system-guid-ctor(system-byte()))
[RandomNumberGenerator.GetBytes Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.randomnumbergenerator.getbytes?view=net-6.0#system-security-cryptography-randomnumbergenerator-getbytes(system-int32))

Comment: You're duplicating part of Santiago's answer: `Set-Clipboard (New-Guid).ToString('B')`

Comment: Though this answer does provide three different ways of adding the curly brackets (the second and third are the same once a `[Guid]` value is created), the way it does so is confusing. It would appear that you're comparing the outputs of four different ways that `$guid` is assigned, but then instead of showing four outputs you only provide it for `.ToString("B")`. Either _show_ the reader that the output formats are all the same or, at least, _tell_ them that they are. Also, what is the purpose of substituting `[Guid]::NewGuid()` for `New-Guid`? Aside from saving a `( )` it muddies the waters.

Comment: @LanceU.Matthews Different ways of doing the same thing. The user will decide which is convenient and less confusing. The output shown is for the first form only.

Comment: Yes, but my point is it's not immediately clear from the answer that it's "Different ways of doing the same thing."  Also, what is the purpose of using `[RandomNumberGenerator]` in `New-CryptoGuid`?  If each byte/bit is random is it even a GUID any more?  GUIDs have a defined structure.

Comment: Check references. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.newguid?view=net-6.0#remarks

Comment: @mklement0 my code is slightly different, but not the same as  Santiago's code - ```(New-Guid).ToString('B') //Santiago's code``` vs ```"{$((New-Guid).Guid)}"``` vs ```[System.Guid]::NewGuid().ToString("B")``` vs ```"{$((New-Guid).Guid)}"```

Comment: @mklement0 ```(New-Guid).Guid``` comes from the question, I just added the braces ```"{$((New-Guid).Guid)}"```

Comment: Yes, I saw that among your references. When it says "If an application requires random data for cryptographic purposes, consider using a static method on the `RandomNumberGenerator` class", that doesn't mean to instead use `RNG` to initialize a `Guid`, as you are, nor is it recommending to mix `RNG` and `Guid` at all; in context, it just means if you want random data then _get it from `RNG` directly_ without the `Guid` "wrapping". Otherwise, nothing in that link answers my question, which I'll simplify: given that a GUID is a structured IDentifier, what is a "crypto GUID" and when is it used?

Comment: At its core, there are two solutions, where `$g` represents a GUID: `"{$($g.Guid}}"` (or, more simply: `"{$g}"`) and `$g.ToString('B')` - both of which 
were present in Santiago's answer at the time you initially posted your answer. That you may alternatively - more verbosely and, in a PowerShel context, more obscurely - 
generate a GUID with `[System.Guid]::NewGuid()` instead of the simpler, PowerShell-idiomatic `New-Guid` is _incidental_ to the solution
and amounts to a _distraction_. The same applies to your `New-CryptoGuid` function, as pointed out by @LanceU.Matthews

Comment: Those are my answers and I can't argue otherwise. It is what you imagine versus what I have answered. I see that you are underestimating my answers thinking about your personal context, you must already know a lot of things about PowerShell but the one who asks says that he is in beginner mode., and I also see that you do not read the references, in the case of the second New-CryptoGuid implementation. Nobody here wants to confuse.

Comment: SO is about sharing & curating knowledge, so comments as seen here seek to ensure that answers provide new, clear, & good info because more signal/less noise is what benefits everyone; it's nothing personal. The last bit of feedback I'll cast into the `[Void]` is that replying to, in short, "The docs don't support your claim" with "You didn't read it" is _not helpful_. Readers are allowed to raise questions — whether out of skepticism, as I did, or just not understanding — and if you're not willing to answer (not link but _answer_) them I'd argue that point shouldn't be included to begin with.